# Why PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser wont parse some sites from localhost?

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I am trying to use [php simple html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and apparently it wont parse some sites from localhost. If i upload the script online then everything is perfect but localhost fails and only on some certain sites. I believe that is because the destination site has some kind of check implemented but I cant think of what it could be...
Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned some websites have mechanisms in place that do not allow unauthorized third-party tools to parse its content.

E.G. Facebook.

If the problem only happens when you're in localhost, you can try to edit your hosts file and add the following line:

`127.0.0.1    mytestingserver.com`

Then access your file the same way you would access it using localhost, but instead of localhost use:

`mytestingserver.com`

For example:

`mytestingserver.com/simple-html-dom.php`

and see if the content loads.

If it works probably the page you're trying to parse only checks whether the request comes from a domain name or not; if it doesn't, then they might have a more sophisticated protection mechanism in place and what you're trying to do is whether not allowed, or there's a better way to do it (an API for example).

Comment: You are genius! That works perfect. The site just checks it comes from a domain name! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! Thanks for your kind word, I'm not a genius... I've just been there, done that :)

Comment: Ok, now i have a problem... ) By setting target site in localhost it turns out my parser is attacking localhost instead of original site )) logical... but how to resolve that?